# Kreyszig - Totality and Parseval Relation

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to follow the proof on page 170 Kreszig's Introductory Functional Analysis of Theorem 3.6-3. I will include a link to the page below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5F9p.jpg

My problem comes from the line starting with "And for every $v \in M$ not contained in..." I understand that $\langle x, v \rangle =0$ by assumption, but how does 
$$ \sum_k \langle x, e_k \rangle \langle e_k, v \rangle =0$$
follow? Is it because $\langle x, e_k \rangle \langle e_k, v \rangle = x_k v_k$, and so the sum becomes
$$ \sum_k x_k v_k $$
This "looks" like an inner product to me, but I don't know how to justify that the sum is zero. In particular, I can't determine that
$$
\langle x,v \rangle = 0 \implies \sum_k x_k v_k =0
$$
since I don't know how the inner product is defined. It's probably me misunderstanding something that is straightforward... thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got it right. The only piece you're missing is that, for any $x\in H$, the following sum converges in $H$:
$$
             y=\sum_{k}\langle x, e_k\rangle e_k .
$$
The norm convergence of this sum, along with the finite additivity and norm continuity of the inner product, imply
\begin{align}
     \langle y,z \rangle & = \langle \lim_{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K} \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k,z\rangle \\
    & = \lim_{K}\langle\sum_{k=1}^{K}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k,z\rangle \\
    & = \lim_{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\langle \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k,z\rangle \\
    & = \lim_{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\langle x,e_k\rangle \langle e_k,z\rangle 
      = \sum_k \langle x,e_k\rangle \langle e_k,z\rangle
\end{align}
The inner product is even jointly continuous because of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequaltiy. So, for example, if $\lim_n x_n = x$ and $\lim_n y_n = y_n$ converge in the norm, then
$$\lim_{n,m}\langle x_n,y_m\rangle = \langle \lim_n x_n, \lim_m y_m \rangle.$$

Comment: Thanks @TrialAndError. I understand now how you got $$ \langle y,v \rangle = \sum_k \langle x, e_k \rangle \langle e_k, v \rangle$$ but I'm still unclear as to why this sum is zero.

Comment: @user288742 : $\langle x_k, v \rangle = 0$ for every $v \in M$ that is not in the set of $\{ e_k \}$.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean $\langle x, v \rangle =0$? I understand that is the assumption about the set $\{e_k\}$, but still I don't get why that means $$\sum_k \langle x, e_k \rangle \langle e_k , v \rangle = \sum_k x_k v_k  =0.$$ Can we assume that $\langle x, v \rangle = \sum_k x_k v_k$?

Comment: "And for every $v\in M$ not contained in (4)" means every $v$ in the orthonormal set $M$ that does not appear in the sum $\sum_{k}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$; to me that would mean $v\in M$ will equal some $e_k$ but the coefficient that the coefficient $\langle x, e_k\rangle$ of that $e_k$ in the sum must be $0$. That's how I would read it. How do you read that statement?